# How to run `webpack --watch` using pm2?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, pm2

I'm using [`pm2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) inside `gulpfile.js` to build dev-server (dev-server consists of *sass watch*, *webpack watch* and *liveserver*)

When I try

```
pm2 start webpack --name wp -- --watch
```

, webpack does not begin watching files, just compiles it once.

To sum up:
How to run `webpack --watch` using pm2?

---

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing pm2 is not passing the argument to webpack. You might be able to add watch in the configuration: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html

Comment: @chapinkapa first of all adding `watch` to config does not activate watching (from docs you provided: **(only used when using CLI or simple node.js API)**). Regarding arguments pm2 do pass parameters to webpack, I've checked it by passing `--json` and looking on output

Comment: Does it work if you run it without pm2? Pm2 just keeps a process running. If the process exits out, pm2 restarts it.

Comment: @chapinkapa yes, it definitely works

Comment: Then why are you running it with pm2?

Comment: @chapinkapa because I need to run few processes using gulp, and there are some issues with it, that's why pm2 is a choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97677/discussion-between-james-akwuh-and-chapinkapa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the issue:

the problem was in `webpack --watch` itself because after update it was not watching files without `sudo`

[Linked discussion](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/675).